# Tumblr OAuth authorization "Missing or invalid oauth_verifier." message solution for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-chrome-extension, tumblr

So I had this problem with getting 400 from `http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxx`.
I use [this Google Chrome OAuth tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) page and just copy the files from there.

And it all worked until one day I had to reauthorize my extension.
And it failed.

When I got to console I so 400 http result code and a message `Missing or invalid oauth_verifier.`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) First to solve: where is the `oauth_verifier`?

I had a look to requests been made by tumblr when authorizing the app.
There was this one `http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxx`.

It was redirected to `chrome-extension://jlaojpiafmimgibgdfbmphfkejnlifdn/chrome_ex_oauth.html?chromeexoauthcallback=true&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=dmbcbNDGj7QatrFznXG587RIM7wI1LG3bnKwYGy5tc2icmUVvE#_=_`.

The verifier is in place so why we just don't get it?
In `chrome_ex_oauth.js` we have this `ChromeExOAuth.formDecode()` method that will decode the current url and get params from it.

And there is a magic check there [line 315](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts/chrome_ex_oauth.js):

```
var keyval = param.split("=");
if (keyval.length == 2) {
```

As you can see, the url ends with `#_=_` which is something strange.
So first I decided to rewrite this method a little to get this `oauth_verifier` out of it.

2) It was not working with `oauth_verifier=dmbcbNDGj7QatrFznXG587RIM7wI1LG3bnKwYGy5tc2icmUVvE#_=_` so I decided to cut this hashtag completely and got: `oauth_verifier=dmbcbNDGj7QatrFznXG587RIM7wI1LG3bnKwYGy5tc2icmUVvE` which started to work.

For me it is still a question: what for is this hashtag at the end of the redirect url that Tumblr wants me to follow?

---

My slightly changed method looks like this:

```
ChromeExOAuth.formDecode = function(encoded) {
  // Cut hash at the end of the url.
  var hash_index = encoded.indexOf('#');
  if ( hash_index > -1 ) {
    encoded = encoded.substring(0, hash_index);
  }

  var params = encoded.split("&");
  var decoded = {};
  for (var i = 0, param; param = params[i]; i++) {
    var keyval = param.split("=");
    if (keyval.length == 2) {
      var key = ChromeExOAuth.fromRfc3986(keyval[0]);
      var val = ChromeExOAuth.fromRfc3986(keyval[1]);
      decoded[key] = val;
    }
  }
  return decoded;
};
```

Comment: Superb thank you! I was having this exact issue in my iOS application. The Tumblr API is weird in my opinion, it supposedly follows the OAuth 1.0a spec, but in my opinion, it does quite a few things differently than other OAuth 1.0a based APIs (i.e.: Twitter).

Comment: @Supertecnoboff wow it is impressive how this bug is still there after 4 years! :)

Comment: It's even more impressive how they still havn't upgraded to OAuth 2.0 haha.